# Open-source inventory agent

Tags: agent, inventory

Can anyone recommend a good open-source inventory-agent, which would help enumerate both the running software and the installed hardware?

I'm actually looking to couple SIGAR (or alternatives) with such agent, to integrate the servers statistics into a single view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JADE: Java Agent DEvelopment Agent.  See their website  http://jade.tilab.com